# Why was the conversion factor of the metric unit bar chosen the way it was?

Tags: pressure, history, units, meteorology

The unit **bar** for pressure is clearly a metric unit, but its order of magnitude is a bit strange. In the centimeter–gram–second system of units we have:

```
1 bar = 1 000 000 baryes = 1 000 000 dyn/cm²
```

so the bar is not "coherent" with this system (the factor is not one). Also in the meter–kilogram–second (and SI) system we get:

```
1 bar = 100 000 pascals = 100 000 N/m²
```

while in the meter–tonne–second system:

```
1 bar = 100 pièzes = 100 sn/m²
```

So my question is simply, where does the conversion factor for bar come from, since it seems to not fit into usual systems? According to the [Wikipedia article *bar*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_%28unit%29) this unit was created already in 1909 by British meteorologist Shaw, but not much detail is provided.

Maybe the factor was simply chosen as the power of ten making the unit closest to the atmospherical pressure at sea level (which is 1.01325 bar by convention, and close to 1.01 bar on average)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1888, a committee of the British Association proposed the name barad for 1 dyne per cm2. In 1900, a congress of physicists recommended the name 'barye' for 1 dyne per cm2, although the original proposal was to use it for 1 megadyne per cm2. In 1903 Richards and Kennely shortened the unit name to bar. Many meteorologists kept using to the old non-CGS pressure units, mm Hg and atmosphere. 
Bjerknes was the first influential meteorologist/oceanographer to adopt the CGS system, but he redefined the bar to 1 megadyne per cm2. Consequently, 1 bar was conveniently close to 1 atmosphere.

Comment: This is a good answer, and I have "accepted" it. However, it would be even better if you could include your sources, i.e. where did you obtain this information?

Comment: My source is an article by [Charles F. Marvin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_F._Marvin) in the Monthly Weather Review from 1918, titled [nomenclature of the unit of absolute pressure](https://docs.lib.noaa.gov/rescue/mwr/046/mwr-046-02-0073.pdf). It contains Bjerknes’ own account of the origin of the unit.

Comment: Thank you very much. I shall give the "blame" to [V. Bjerknes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilhelm_Bjerknes) and [J. W. Sandström](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johan_Sandstr%C3%B6m), then.

Answer (score 2):

The $\text{pascal}$ seems of a much later date than the $\text{bar}$. In fact, it seems that, at some time, the $\text{bar}$ was *adjusted* a bit *away* from the average air pressure on earth (its originally intended definition), to get it "in line" with the SI units, and therefore also with the new or later $1~\text{Pa}=1~{\text{kg}\over\text{m}\cdot\text{s}^2}$.

> Meteorologists worldwide have for a long time measured atmospheric pressure in bars, which was originally equivalent to the average air pressure on Earth [...]. After the introduction of SI units, many preferred to preserve the customary pressure figures. Consequently, the bar was *redefined* as 100,000 pascals, which is only slightly lower than standard air pressure on Earth. [My emphasis.]

<sup>[*Pascal (unit)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28unit%29)</sup>

---

*As noted in the comments below, this answer (and, perhaps, the Wikipedia quote) might or might not stand up to scrutiny. Further digging in history seems necessary, but I dug a bit and can't find anything really substantiating this reading. However, I* also *didn't find anything conclusively and explicitly pointing towards a different reading (i.e., that the magnitude of the $\text{bar}$ is the same now as it was when the $\text{bar}$ was adopted initially).*

Comment: This does not convince me that the magnitude of the bar unit was actually changed, although I admit that is one way of reading that quote. I think the bar was originally defined from metric units for length and mass, and the second. Of course it was not originally *defined* as 100'000 pascals as the pascal is a newer unit. Since, today, the pascal is the basic unit, today people define the bar from the pascal. But this change does not necessarily mean that the *magnitude* of the bar was ever changed.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That's all I have to offer. :(

Comment: Well, either you gave the correct answer, or you found an error in Wikipedia (which would be interesting in itself). So the question is now, was the bar a metric unit from the start (for example defined by $10^6~\frac{\text{g}}{\text{cm}\cdot\text{s}^2}$), or was it originally defined at another magnitude (just over 101 kPa) and only later changed to be metric?